# Use schroot replacing lxc

Tags: linux, chroot, lxc

I have been using lxc for a while, but I found the configuration and documentation hard to follow, is not clear what to do sometimes and any new version means a lot of changes in my code.

I was looking for schroot, so I want to know if *there is a way to complete replace lxc with schroot?* _can I run /sbin/init with schroot?_

I found this post: http://johnlewis.ie/using-schroot-instead-of-lxc-containers/ is then possible to start a bunch of services in the same chroot, but I want first to check  also if I can run a whole system.

I imagine that some security issues must be solve manually now, but I prefer that that the undocumented magic in lxc, but *is there any security disadvantage in use schroot vs lxc?*

*I like the notion of have a (almost) complete new system in the lxc containers, but is that possible to get using just schroot?*

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using LXC/schroot for?

Comment: To isolate untrusted code execution of long running processes like web apps or task managers, which are configured by an user and it can do nasty thing in the system.

Answer (score 2):

Schroot only virtualizes the filesystem; it does not limit resource utilization, network access, ability to send signals, ability to see other processes running on the system, etc. So untrusted code could use up all your memory, send spam, or kill processes running as the same user. While you could run /sbin/init in there, it wouldn't be pid 1, and your init scripts could "see" all the processes from the base OS and other chroots, which would probably require more code modifications than lxc would.

If you're looking to run potentially hostile (i.e. net-submitted) code, I'd definitely stick with LXC.